# sendText() & _sendDirectItem() & _prepareRecipients() must be of the type array, integer given

Tags: php, arrays, instagram, instagram-api

i get this errors in my log :

```
ERROR - 2018-04-07 02:10:23 --> Severity: 4096 --> Argument 1 passed to InstagramAPI\Request\Direct::sendText() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /home/instapanel/public_html/app/helpers/instagram_helper.php on line 5968 and defined /home/instapanel/public_html/app/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/src/Request/Direct.php 468
ERROR - 2018-04-07 02:10:23 --> Severity: 4096 --> Argument 2 passed to InstagramAPI\Request\Direct::_sendDirectItem() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /home/instapanel/public_html/app/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/src/Request/Direct.php on line 489 and defined /home/instapanel/public_html/app/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/src/Request/Direct.php 1002
ERROR - 2018-04-07 02:10:23 --> Severity: 4096 --> Argument 1 passed to InstagramAPI\Request\Direct::_prepareRecipients() must be of the type array, integer given, called in /home/instapanel/public_html/app/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/src/Request/Direct.php on line 1132 and defined /home/instapanel/public_html/app/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php/src/Request/Direct.php 928
```

i think its from this codes from instagram_helper.php :

```
if (!empty($users))
{
foreach($users as $user)
    {
    if (!empty($user))
        {
        $info = $i->people->getFriendship($user->id);
        if ($info->status == "ok")
            {
            $history = $CI->db->select("*")->where("pk", $user->username)->where("type", $data->category)->where("account_id", $data->account_id)->get(INSTAGRAM_HISTORY)->row();
            if (empty($history) && $info->following == "" && $info->outgoing_request == "" && $info->followed_by == 1)
                {
                $follow = $i->people->follow($user->id);

                // echo "<a href='https://instagram.com/".$user->username."' target='_blank'>".$user->username."</a>";

                if ($follow->status == "ok")
                    {
                    $messages = (array)json_decode($data->message);
                    $message_index = array_rand((array)json_decode($data->message));
                    if (!empty($messages))
                        {
                        $message = $spintax->process($messages[$message_index]);
                        if ($message != "")
                            {
                            $mess = $i->direct->sendText($user->id, $message);
                            }
                        }

                    $user->pk = $user->id;
                    $response = array(
                        "st" => "success",
                        "data" => json_encode($user) ,
                        "code" => $user->username,
                        "txt" => l('Successfully')
                    );
                    }

                break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code is from an auto-pilot script for Instagram name (EasyGram). in last update developer give me new instagram_helper.php file but its not work with (AutoDirect to new Followers). any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
$mess = $i->direct->sendText($user->id, $message);
```

with

```
$mess = $i->direct->sendText([$user->id], $message);
```

Looking at the source code you can see:

```
/**
 * Send a direct text message to a user's inbox.
 *
 * @param array  $recipients An array with "users" or "thread" keys.
 *                           To start a new thread, provide "users" as an array
 *                           of numerical UserPK IDs. To use an existing thread
 *                           instead, provide "thread" with the thread ID.
 * @param string $text       Text message.
 * @param array  $options    An associative array of optional parameters, including:
 *                           "client_context" - predefined UUID used to prevent double-posting.
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 * @throws \InstagramAPI\Exception\InstagramException
 *
 * @return \InstagramAPI\Response\DirectSendItemResponse
 */

public function sendText(
    array $recipients,
    $text,
    array $options = [])
```

First parameter ($recipients)  must be an array.

Comment: thanks for quick reply <3 now **errors not shown and this problem solved** but still _direct message_ not work at all :(